# Where is the "wiki" section?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

stackoverflow had a section like wiki with code exemples and a lot of great tips but now cant find it. Used it a year ago.

Was it deleted?

Comment: It is gone, sadly.

Comment: I think Documentation made more sense than Team / Careers.

Comment: @Script47, you can charge money for Teams / Careers...